# VB.Net MessageBox.Show() moves my form to the back

Tags: vb.net, mdi, messagebox, mdichild

I have an MDI application. When I show a message box using MessageBox.Show(), the entire application disappears behind all of my open windows when I dismiss the message box.

The code is not doing anything special. In fact, here is the line that invokes the message box from within an MDI Child form:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} saved successfully.", Me.BusinessUnitTypeName), "Save Successful", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly)
```

Me.BusinessUnitTypeName() is a read only property getter that returns a string, depending upon the value of a member variable. There are no side effects in this property.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, and I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the last parameter, `MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxoptions(VS.80).aspx):

> DefaultDesktopOnly will cause the
>   application that raised the MessageBox
>   to lose focus. The MessageBox that is
>   displayed will not use visual styles.
>   For more information, see Rendering
>   Controls with Visual Styles.

The last parameter allows communication of a background Windows Service with the active desktop through means of csrss.exe! See Bart de Smet's [blog post](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2004/12/03/488.aspx) for details.

Comment: Thanks also for the blog link. Very good research and good information to file away for further use!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly` parameter and it will work correctly.

`DefaultDesktopOnly` specifies that "**The message box is displayed on the active desktop**" which causes the focus loss.

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer was functionally similar to Mitch Wheat's and came in at the same time. I gave his the nod because of the MSDN snippet/reference.

Answer (score 1):

These answers are correct, but I wanted to add another point. I came across this question while working with someone else's code. A simple message box was causing the front most window to move to the back:

MessageBox.Show("Hello").

Turns out, there was a BindingSource.Endedit command before the MessageBox. The BindingSource wasn't connected to any controls yet, but it caused the window to change z-positions.

I am only including this note since my search brought me to this question and I thought it might be helpful to someone else.